# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a mi botón por su id?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragment

He estado aprendiendo a usar Navigation, y vi esta forma usando fragments, y todo iba bien(Voy siguiendo un tutorial en un vídeo), pero tengo un problema cuando estoy en el fragment para querer agregar el ID de mi botón y agregarle el **.setOnClickListener**, sucede que no reconocé el ID de mi botón y por ende no puedo agregarlo.

Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle
import.androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class fragmento1 : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento1, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // error
        btn_Ir_Pantalla2.setOnClickListener {}
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".fragmento1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/soy_la_pantalla_1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Ir_Pantalla2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ir a la pantalla 2">

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: en que parte se supone que estás intentando agregar un clickListener?

Comment: En el fragment1(kt), debajo del override fun onViewCreated. Se supone que se debe agregar el id del botón(btn_Ir_Pantalla2), pero si lo intento escribir no se puede y marca error, y al no dejarme ponerlo no puedo agregarle el setOnClick, de forma que quede btn_Ir_Pantalla2.setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa forma de acceder a los elementos del layout directamente con su id era posible gracias a una feature llamada `Kotlin synthetics` que pertenecía al plugin `Kotlin Android Extensions`. Ese plugin ahora está obsoleto porque fue reemplazado por [View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Si no quieres usar view binding, la otra opción es usar el método `findViewById()`

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_Ir_Pantalla2).setOnClickListener {
    ...
}
```

No sé que tutorial estés siguiendo pero seguramente no es uno oficial. [Aquí](https://youtu.be/xITkfPIaStU?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9VpBMZUS9geQtc5RJ2RsUd&t=64) puedes ver videos oficiales sobre el navigation component.
Todos estos temas (navegación y view binding) también están explicados en el [curso oficial de android](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course)